# What is the intended use of categories?

Tags: categories, craft-features

Just figuring out the craft interface and finding all sorts of useful features. Just can't figure out what the purpose of "categories" is in the settings.

Would be much appreciated if anyone could please tell me how this function is intended to be used and set-up?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Categories Settings let you set up [Category Groups](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/categories), define some behaviors for your Category Groups (for example, if you want them to have URLs and the pattern of those URLs), and assign Custom Fields to those Category Groups (which would allow all categories in that group to have custom fields just like all Entries have the same custom fields in a section).

Comment: Thank you, went through my site while reading the link you posted. Makes sense now. Will be a useful feature to organize URLs of similar groups.